# Service snmpd calls gettimeofday syscall too many times

Tags: centos, networking, strace, snmp

Recently I am facing an issue with snmpd service. I have a Linux box running CentOS 6.9, when I issue an snmpwalk on localhost usually all I get is a timeout, then I try adding a timeout value of 10 seconds, the result is better but still painfully slow. I decided to dig deeper into the kernel using strace and found out that the snmpd service tries to call for gettimeofday multiple times before answering to the snmp request. Comparing to other Linux boxes that are running Debian 8 and Centos 6.3, their snmpd service doesn't call gettimeofday at all. Here's the result that I have:

```
rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-6-9.el6.12.3.x86_64

service snmpd status
snmpd (pid  28244) is running...

strace -r -e trace=gettimeofday -p 28244
Process 28244 attached
     0.000000 gettimeofday({1516589055, 372419}, NULL) = 0
     0.000048 gettimeofday({1516589055, 372448}, NULL) = 0
     0.000015 gettimeofday({1516589055, 372463}, NULL) = 0
     0.000015 gettimeofday({1516589055, 372477}, NULL) = 0
     0.003271 gettimeofday({1516589055, 375751}, NULL) = 0

0.000013 munmap(0x7f1950abf000, 4096) = 0
     0.000086 open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth3/forwarding", O_RDONLY) = 11
     0.000028 fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
     0.000015 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1950abf000
     0.000015 read(11, "0\n", 1024)     = 2
     0.000017 close(11)                 = 0
     0.000012 munmap(0x7f1950abf000, 4096) = 0
     0.000017 open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/eth3/base_reachable_time_ms", O_RDONLY) = 11
     0.000017 fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
     0.000013 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1950abf000
     0.000014 read(11, "30000\n", 1024) = 6
     0.000016 close(11)                 = 0
     0.000012 munmap(0x7f1950abf000, 4096) = 0
     0.000015 read(9, "", 1024)         = 0
     0.000026 close(9)                  = 0
     0.000015 munmap(0x7f1950ac0000, 4096) = 0
     0.000014 close(10)                 = 0
     0.000028 gettimeofday({1516099695, 497691}, NULL) = 0
     0.000015 gettimeofday({1516099695, 497705}, NULL) = 0
     0.000012 gettimeofday({1516099695, 497718}, NULL) = 0
     0.000016 gettimeofday({1516099695, 497734}, NULL) = 0
     0.000012 gettimeofday({1516099695, 497746}, NULL) = 0
     0.000013 gettimeofday({1516099695, 497758}, NULL) = 0
```

Comparing to the strace result of snmpd service on another Linux box running CentOS 6.3:

```
rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-6-3.el6.centos.9.x86_64

Process 4566 attached - interrupt to quit
     0.000000 select(10, [4 6 7 9], [], [], {1, 160003}) = 0 (Timeout)
     1.161298 open("/proc/diskstats", O_RDONLY) = 10
     0.000109 fstat(10, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
     0.000245 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6e1d035000
     0.000047 read(10, "   1       0 ram0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "..., 1024) = 1024
     0.000109 read(10, "0 sda 240731 163874 8048386 2853"..., 1024) = 611
     0.000061 read(10, "", 1024)        = 0
     0.000023 close(10)                 = 0
     0.000064 munmap(0x7f6e1d035000, 4096) = 0
     0.000036 open("/proc/stat", O_RDONLY) = 10
     0.000034 read(10, "cpu  3775592 27347 3516548 70619"..., 4095) = 866
     0.000056 close(10)                 = 0
     0.000028 open("/proc/vmstat", O_RDONLY) = 10
     0.000031 read(10, "nr_free_pages 75722\nnr_inactive_"..., 4095) = 1964
     0.000042 close(10)                 = 0
     0.000037 select(10, [4 6 7 9], [], [], {4, 999068}) = 0 (Timeout)
     5.003442 open("/proc/diskstats", O_RDONLY) = 10
     0.000082 fstat(10, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
     0.000034 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6e1d035000
     0.000029 read(10, "   1       0 ram0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "..., 1024) = 1024
     0.000126 read(10, "0 sda 240731 163874 8048386 2853"..., 1024) = 611
     0.000045 read(10, "", 1024)        = 0
     0.000023 close(10)                 = 0
     0.000076 munmap(0x7f6e1d035000, 4096) = 0
     0.000036 open("/proc/stat", O_RDONLY) = 10
     0.000037 read(10, "cpu  3775592 27347 3516551 70619"..., 4095) = 866
     0.000084 close(10)                 = 0
     0.000045 open("/proc/vmstat", O_RDONLY) = 10
     0.000035 read(10, "nr_free_pages 75722\nnr_inactive_"..., 4095) = 1964
     0.000100 close(10)                 = 0
     0.000055 select(10, [4 6 7 9], [], [], {2, 88417}
```

Is there any specific configurations that I may not aware of for snmpd service to call gettimeofday too many times before responding to a request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting. I once had this issue, if I remember how I solved it, I will get bsck to you.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: great, can't wait for your reply!

Comment: I cannot remember with which daemon I had this problem: maybe Apache...I left an answer. btw, thanks for answering the message, I left  original message as a marker to remind me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are issues were having your TZ variable set can save you *thousands* of system calls due to the way time libraries are coded.

They actually are related to your problem, and as such I will need feedback.

From [How setting the TZ environment variable avoids thousands of system calls](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/02/21/set-environment-variable-save-thousands-of-system-calls/)

> To avoid extra system calls on server processes where you won’t be
>   updating the timezone (or can restart processes when you do) simply
>   set the TZ environment variable to :/etc/localtime (or some other
>   timezone file of your choice) for a process. This will cause glibc to
>   avoid making extra (and unnecessary) system calls.
>
> It turns out that the localtime function in glibc will check if the TZ
>   environment variable is set. If it is not set (the two Ubuntus I’ve
>   tested do not set it), then glibc will use the stat system call every
>   time localtime is called.
>
> In other words: your system supports calling the time system call via
>   the Linux kernel’s vDSO to avoid the cost of switching to the kernel.
>   But, as soon as your program calls time, it calls localtime
>   immediately after, which invokes a system call anyway. So, you’ve
>   eliminated one system call with the vDSO, but replaced it with
>   another.

Be aware that file accesses also usually use time-related system calls. Try to use in the configuration files of SNMP numeric MIBS instead of their names. (it might have only impact at `snmpd` starting time and not make much of a difference afterwards).

As new file accesses make use of time related system calls, it is normal you will see some of them when starting `snmpd` -  you might be comparing a system without MIBs installed with another one with MIBs installed.

Comment: I can't say the quoted thing might not be an issue, but syscall in question is different, `stat("/etc/localtime")` vs. `gettimeofday()`

Comment: @ilkkachu Have you tried to do something about it?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I've added the timezone value, still getting gettimeofday called every time.

And also the snmpd config is the same on all linux boxes that I mentioned. The OIDs in their config are all numeric